# cordova: get user profile info google oauth

Tags: cordova, google-oauth

I am implementing google oauth in cordova app. It is working fine at the moment and i am getting Token from google.

Problem is i am trying to get user details like name, email, profile pic etc.

Any advise how can i get the details.

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
        var $loginButton = $('#logins a');
    var $loginStatus = $('#logins p');
    $(document).on('click', '#google', function (e) { 

        googleapi.authorize({
            client_id: 'client_id',
            client_secret: 'secret',
            redirect_uri: 'http://localhost',
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
        }).done(function(data) {
            $loginStatus.html('Access Token: ' + data.access_token);
        }).fail(function(data) {
            $loginStatus.html(data.error);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Anyways i have changed the scope to email but data is in array and i am not able to print the data array. Even array.length is not giving me any value. I am getting undefined.

Comment: Maybe this can help:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/